# When y= 1, logit is infinity. How can you regress that? Yet somehow, that's logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

Logistic regression essentially means taking the logit of your response proportions, p, and then doing standard regression. Consider the case where one p is 1.

logit(1) = log(1/(1-1)) = infinity. How can you do regression with infinity?

That is, if one of your observed proportions p is 1, then you are trying to find the line that minimises the sum of squared differences from a set of points that include infinity. How does this not drive the regression line to always have infinite slope?

Comment: You have mischaracterized logistic regression: one does not take the logits of the data but instead models the data as outcomes of random variables whose *parameters* are expressed in terms of logits.  For more information see *inter alia* the [Wikipedia article on generalized linear models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model).

Comment: OK, thanks! I misunderstood how the link function is used, and thus misunderstood glms. I'll be looking for a more basic tutorial than what I see in wikipedia.

Comment: I have offered an answer, Alex, to help bridge that gap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question characterizes logistic regression as

$$\text{logit}(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \varepsilon$$

and proposes to fit this model using least squares.  It points out that because $y$ is a binary ($0$-$1$) variable, $\text{logit}(y)$ is undefined (or should be considered infinite), which is--to say the least--problematic!

The resolution of this conundrum is to avoid taking the logit of $y$ but instead apply its *inverse,* the *logistic function*

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x)},$$

to the right hand side.  Because $y$ on the left hand side still is a random variable with possible outcomes $0$ and $1$, it must be a Bernoulli variable: that is, what we need to know about it is the *chance that $y=1$,*  written $\Pr(y=1).$  Therefore we make another attempt in the form

$$\Pr(y=1) = f(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x).$$

This is an example of a [generalized linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model).  Its parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are typically (but not necessarily) found using Maximum Likelihood.

To understand this better, many people find it instructive to *create* synthetic datasets according to this model (instead of analyzing actual data, where the true model is unknown).  We will look at how that might be coded in `R`, which is well suited to expressing and simulating statistical models.  First, though, let's inspect its results.

[image: Figure]

The data are shown as jittered points (they have been randomly shifted slightly in the horizontal direction to resolve overlaps).  The *true* underlying probability function is plotted in solid red.  The probability function fit using Maximum Likliehood is plotted in dashed gray.

You can see that where the red curve is high--which means the chance of $y=1$ is high--most of the data are $1$'s, whereas where the red curve drops to low levels, most of the data are $0$'s.  *The height of the curve stipulates the chance that the response will be a $1$.*  In logistic regression, the *curve* usually has the sigmoidal shape of the logistic function, while the data are always either at $y=1$ or $y=0$.

Reading over the code, which is written for expressive clarity, will help make these descriptions precise.

```r
#
# Synthesize some data.
#
set.seed(17)                        # Allows results to be reproduced exactly
n <- 8                              # Number of distinct x values
k <- 4                              # Number of independent obs's for each x
x <- rep(1:n, 4)                    # Independent values
beta <- c(3, -1)                    # True parameters
logistic <- function(x) 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
probability <- function(x, b) logistic(b[1] + b[2]*x)
y <- rbinom(n*k, size=1, prob=probability(x, beta))   # Simulated data
#
# Fit the data using a logistic regression.
#
summary(fit <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial(link="logit")))
#
# Plot the data, the true underlying probability function, and the fitted one.
#
jitter <- runif(n*k, -1/3, 1/3)     # Displaces points to resolve overlaps
plot(x+jitter, y, type="p", xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Data with true and fitted models")
curve(probability(x, beta), col="Red", lwd=2, add=TRUE)
curve(probability(x, coef(fit)), col="Gray", lwd=2, lty=2, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: I do not understand "Because y on the left hand side", which left hand side? There is above only a logit(y) and logit(1) or logit(0) is infininity. However in the shown plot there is only a range from 0 to 1. Still confusing, how the logit is regressed.

Comment: @granular the only equation preceding that remark has a left side and a right side.

Comment: Nothertheless, still do not understand the answer and a new posed question that is similar was deleted. And there is a bad equation style in commentaries. So we try to fulfill $1=\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(-(\beta_0+\beta_1x))}$ if the dependent variable is 1 and $0=\frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(-(\beta_0+\beta_1x))}$ if the dependent variable is 0 for all corresponding independent variables?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you do use the log odds ratio for the regression, but the equation for "p" instead which has values of 0 or 1 in the sample. The regression equation is estimated via iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS).

The method can be found here [Manually calculating logistic regression coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220304/manually-calculating-logistic-regression-coefficient/220306)

Answer (score -2):

You got logistic regression kind of backwards (see whuber's comment on your question). True, the logit of 1 is infinity. But that's ok, because at no stage do you take the logit of the observed p's.

Consider standard regression, for simplicity using a single x variable:

```
y = b0 + b1*x
```

Logistic regression means that y is not interpreted as the response proportions (the p's), but rather as the logit of the response proportions. So let's say a p = 1. Because its logit is infinity, with finite b0 and b1, the logistic regression will never exactly predict it except asymptotically as x approaches infinity.

With the observed proportion of 1, the logistic regression for that x can however predict a very high probability (but again, never as high as 1), say .99. Then, the probability of observing a proportion of 1 for a limited number of trials can easily be large. So when logistic regression corresponds to maximizing the likelihood, the probability of that data point given the model can be high. So, a proportion of 1 need not be more influential (to "drive the regression to always have infinite slope") than any other proportion.

This is also true for other sigmoidal-link regression types such as probit.

Comment: @This seems unclear.  Maximum-likelihood logistic regression certainly can give infinite odds ratio estimates & hence predicted probabilities of 1 or 0 - the phenomenon is called [separation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression).

Comment: It also seems that this answer misunderstands the question, which was about *one* response, not the whole set of responses.

Comment: This answer starts well but by the second paragraph it makes exactly the same mistake about logistic regression as the OP.

Comment: @whuber, I believe this *is* the OP.